# Creating multiple abstract classes javascript ES6

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6, abstract-class

Today I came up with an idea, to use Proxy object, to allow creation of multiple abstract classes, for example

```
const abstract = abstractClass => new Proxy(abstractClass,{
  construct: (target, args) => { throw new Error('Error, class was declared as abstract!') }
});

class A{}
class B{}
class C{}
[A,B,C] = [A,B,C].map(c => abstract(c));
```

So my question is whether this solution has any drawbacks, and if so, what they are.

Comment: I think that abstract classes should be part of compilation, and not runtime. You should check typescript [abstract classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The drawback is that `Proxy` cannot be reliably polyfilled in ES5 and it is slow.

A good recipe is to solve this with inheritance:

```
class Abstract {
    constructor() {
        if (Object.getPrototypeOf(this.constructor) === Abstract
            || this.constructor === Abstract) {
            throw new Error("Cannot instantiate abstract class");
        }
    }
};

class AbstractFoo extends Abstract {...}

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {...}
```

`Abstract` and `AbstractFoo` will throw an error when instantiated directly.

ES.next decorators can be used to make the task easier:

```
function abstract(target) {
    return class Abstract extends target {
        constructor(...args) {
            super(...args);
            if (this.constructor === Abstract) {
                throw new Error("Cannot instantiate abstract class");
            }
        }
    };
}
@abstract
class AbstractFoo {...}

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {...}
```

Since decorators are basically helper functions, they can be applied directly in plain ES6:

```
const AbstractFoo = abstract(class AbstractFoo {...});

class ConcreteFoo extends AbstractFoo {...}
```

Notice that in the case of a decorator original constructor will be evaluated before throwing an error, this is the price of using `extends`. The workaround is to use a function instead of class and inherit it from `target` manually, similarly to [TypeScript `__extends`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Foo%20extends%20Bar%20%7B%7D) and [Babel `__inherits`](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&evaluate=false&lineWrap=false&presets=es2015%2Ces2016%2Ces2017%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&targets=&browsers=&builtIns=false&debug=false&experimental=true&loose=false&spec=false&playground=false&code_lz=MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oFMAeAXZA7AJjAQmAE7QDeAvkA&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D&%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09this.patchwork%28definition,%20context%29;%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%0A%20%20%0A%09configure%20=%20function%28config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09for%20%28var%20key%20in%20config%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09if%20%28key%20in%20this._config%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this._config[key]%20%3D%20config[key]%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09debug%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.debug%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09warn%20%3D%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09if%20%28this._config.debug%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09var%20args%20%3D%20arguments.length%20%3E%201%20%3F%20[Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29]%20%3A%20arguments%3B%0A%09%09%09var%20console%20%3D%20root.console%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%3B%0A%09%09%09return%20%28console.warn%20%7C%7C%20console.log%20%7C%7C%20function%20%28%29%20%7B%7D%29.apply%28console%2C%20args%29%3B%0A%09%09%7D%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patch%20%3D%20function%20patch%28origFn%2C%20patchFns%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09name%20%3D%20name%20%7C%7C%20%27%27%3B%0A%0A%09%09var%20wrapper%20%3D%20function%20patchWrapper%28%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%2F%2F%20patch%20functions%20can%20substitute%20original%20args%20and%20result%0A%09%09%09var%20obj%20%3D%20%7B%20args%3A%20Array.prototype.slice.call%28arguments%29%20%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns%20&%20patchFns.length%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.pre%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Prepatched%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.pre.apply%28this,%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.over%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Overridden%20@%20%27%20%20%20name,%20obj%29;%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20=%20patchFns.over.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28patchFns.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Postpatched%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09patchFns.post.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args.concat%28[obj]%29%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09this.debug%28%27Passed%20%40%20%27%20%2B%20name%2C%20obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09obj.result%20%3D%20origFn.apply%28this%2C%20obj.args%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09if%20%28callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09callbackFn%28obj%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%0A%09%09%09return%20obj.result%3B%0A%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09wrapper.pachted%20%3D%20true%3B%20%2F%2F%20double-pachting%20control%0A%09%09return%20wrapper%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pre%20%3D%20function%20pre%28origFn%2C%20preFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20preFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09post%20%3D%20function%20post%28origFn%2C%20postFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20post%3A%20postFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09over%20%3D%20function%20over%28origFn%2C%20overFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20over%3A%20overFn%20%7D%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09pass%20%3D%20function%20pass%28origFn%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%20%7B%0A%09%09return%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20name%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09patchwork%20%3D%20function%20patchwork%28tree%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%28function%20process%28nodes%2C%20context%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09for%20%28var%20nodeName%20in%20nodes%20%7C%7C%20%7B%7D%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20node%20%3D%20nodes[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09var%20origFn%20%3D%20context[nodeName]%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%0A%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27origFn%27%2C%20origFn]%2C%20[%27context%27%2C%20context]%2C%20[%27nodes%27%2C%20nodes]%2C%20[%27nodeName%27%2C%20nodeName]%29%0A%0A%09%09%09%09var%20callbackFn%20%3D%20!node.then%20%3F%20null%20%3A%20function%20%28obj%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28%27process%27%2C%20obj%29%0A%09%09%09%09%09process%28node.then%2C%20obj.result%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%3B%0A%0A%09%09%09%09if%20%28!%28%27pachted%27%20in%20origFn%29%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09if%20%28node.pre%20%7C%7C%20node.over%20%7C%7C%20node.post%29%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20%7B%20pre%3A%20node.pre%2C%20over%3A%20node.over%2C%20post%3A%20node.post%20%7D%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%20else%20%7B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%09context[nodeName]%20%3D%20this.patch%28origFn%2C%20null%2C%20node.title%2C%20callbackFn%29%3B%0A%09%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%09%09%2F%2F%20console.log%28[%27context[nodeName]%27%2C%20context[nodeName]]%2C%20[%27nodes[nodeName]%27%2C%20nodes[nodeName]]%29%0A%09%09%09%7D%0A%09%09%7D%29%28tree%2C%20context%29%3B%0A%09%7D%3B%0A%7D) helper functions, this way an error could be thrown before `super()`. Another workaround is to use `new.target` (currently cannot be transpiled to ES5 with Babel):

```
function abstract(target) {
    return class Abstract extends target {
        constructor(...args) {
            if (new.target === Abstract) {
                throw new Error("Cannot instantiate abstract class");
            }
            super(...args);
        }
    };
}
```

A cleaner way is to use TypeScript (as it was suggested in comments), it introduces abstract classes as language feature and takes care of it at design time. This allows to not pollute prototype chain.

Comment: Babel support isn't quite there yet, but you can also use `new.target === Abstract` to check instead, which can be used before `super(...)`

Comment: @loganfsmyth I didn't mention `new.target` exactly because of that, but yes, you are right, in native ES6 it's the way to go.

Comment: Fair. The question never mentions Babel though, so if you're on Node it's perfectly fine.

Comment: @loganfsmyth [Babel 7 will support `new.target`](https://github.com/babel/babel/pull/5906) - at least transpiling it into `this.constructor`.

Comment: Yup! Just not out of alpha yet.